dataframe to json columns with multiple values read as one string
I am trying to read a csv file into a dataframe to transform that into nested jsons. The deliminter in the csv file is ';'. After loading the data into a dataframe, following is what I get:



name
frequency
frequency_start_date
frequency_count
schedule_type
day_of_week
Comments




Pattern 1
daily
2022-02-01
1
weekdays
Monday
null


Pattern 2
daily
2024-01-01
1, 5
weekdays, weekdays
Monday, Tuesday
null, null


Pattern 3
daily
2021-03-21
1, 2
weekdays, weekdays
Thursday,Friday
null, null



This is the code I wrote to load the csv as a dataframe:
df1_data = pd.read_csv(csv1, delimiter=';', keep_default_na=False, dtype=object)

This is the code I wrote to transform the dataframe into json:
nested_cols = ['frequency_count', 'schedule_type', 'day_of_week']

df1_data['patterns'] = df1_data[nested_cols].to_dict('records')

df1_nested2 = df1_data[['name', 'frequency', 'frequency_start_date', 'patterns', 'comments']].to_json(orient='records', indent=4)

When I run this, I get the following:
[
    {
        "name": "Pattern 1",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2022-02-01",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": "1",
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        "comments": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Pattern 2",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2024-01-01",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": "1, 5",
            "schedule_type": "weekdays,weekdays",
            "day_of_week": "null, null"
        },
        "comments": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Pattern 3",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2021-03-21",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": "1, 2",
            "schedule_type": "weekdays,weekdays",
            "day_of_week": "null, null"
        },
        "comments": null
    }
]

But this is what I want:
[
    {
        "name": "Pattern 1",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2022-02-01",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": "1",
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        "comments": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Pattern 2",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2024-01-01",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": 1,
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        {
            "frequency_count": 5,
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        "comments": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Pattern 3",
        "frequency": "daily",
        "frequency_start_date": "2021-03-21",
        "patterns": {
            "frequency_count": 1,
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        {
            "frequency_count": 2,
            "schedule_type": "weekdays",
            "day_of_week": null
        },
        "comments": null
    }
]

This is where I am stuck. Is this an issue with csv into dataframe? Or dataframe into json? It seems that the columns where there are multiple values are read as strings. I read questions posted at StackOverflow but none of them actually had this issue or answers did not help me to solve this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Beta

I ran a test to change the column type of frequency_count from object to int with df1_data['frequency_count'] = df1_data['frequency_count'].astype(int) but I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1, 1'

But I do have a space after the comma so not sure why I still can't change the column type.

What you have as your desired output is not valid JSON.

Thank you so much @BeRTme. You guided me to see what I was missing. The output JSON is actually valid as I am able to use that with Postman to make the API call.

Given:
        name frequency frequency_start_date frequency_count       schedule_type      day_of_week    Comments
0  Pattern 1     daily           2022-02-01               1            weekdays           Monday         NaN
1  Pattern 2     daily           2024-01-01            1, 5  weekdays, weekdays  Monday, Tuesday  null, null
2  Pattern 3     daily           2021-03-21            1, 2  weekdays, weekdays  Thursday,Friday  null, null

Doing:

Convert the strings to lists:

multi_cols = ["frequency_count", "schedule_type", "day_of_week", "Comments"]

for col in multi_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(", ?") # regex


Explode these columns:

df = df.explode(multi_cols)


Make this patterns column and fix the Comments column:

df["patterns"] = df[["frequency_count", "schedule_type", "day_of_week"]].to_dict("records")
df["Comments"] = df["Comments"].fillna("null")


Pivot and export to json:

output = df.pivot_table(
    index=["name", "frequency", "frequency_start_date", "Comments"], 
    values="patterns", 
    aggfunc=list, 
).reset_index().to_json(orient="records", indent=4)
print(output)

Output:
[
    {
        "name":"Pattern 1",
        "frequency":"daily",
        "frequency_start_date":"2022-02-01",
        "Comments":"null",
        "patterns":[
            {
                "frequency_count":"1",
                "schedule_type":"weekdays",
                "day_of_week":"Monday"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Pattern 2",
        "frequency":"daily",
        "frequency_start_date":"2024-01-01",
        "Comments":"null",
        "patterns":[
            {
                "frequency_count":"1",
                "schedule_type":"weekdays",
                "day_of_week":"Monday"
            },
            {
                "frequency_count":"5",
                "schedule_type":"weekdays",
                "day_of_week":"Tuesday"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Pattern 3",
        "frequency":"daily",
        "frequency_start_date":"2021-03-21",
        "Comments":"null",
        "patterns":[
            {
                "frequency_count":"1",
                "schedule_type":"weekdays",
                "day_of_week":"Thursday"
            },
            {
                "frequency_count":"2",
                "schedule_type":"weekdays",
                "day_of_week":"Friday"
            }
        ]
    }
]


Thanks to @BeRT2me, the final code for this is the following:
nested_cols = ['frequency_count', 'schedule_type', 'day_of_week']

# splitting the strings in nested columns
for col in nested_cols:
    df1_data[col] = df1_data[col].str.split(',')

#exploding the columns
df1_data.explode(nested_cols)

#changed the frequency_count type to int as a number is always expected
df1_data['frequency_count'] = df1_data['frequency_count'].astype(int)

df1_data['patterns'] = df1_data[nested_cols].to_dict("records")

# Using @BeRT2me response:
output = df.pivot_table(
index=["name", "frequency", "frequency_start_date", "Comments"], 
values="patterns", 
aggfunc=list).reset_index().to_json(orient="records", indent=4)

# replacing the string "null" by null in json
df1_nested = df1_nested.replace('"null"', 'null')

The output is:
[
{
    "pattern_name":"daily_pattern_cadence_start_after_effective_start",
    "cadence":"Daily",
    "cadence_start_date":"2023-02-01",
    "comments":null,
    "patterns":[
        {
            "cadence_count":1,
            "weekend_type":"Western",
            "annual_reset":"No",
            "fixed_day_of_week":null,
            "effective_start_date":"2022-12-31",
            "effective_end_date":"2023-12-31"
        },
        {
            "cadence_count":1,
            "weekend_type":" Western",
            "annual_reset":" No",
            "fixed_day_of_week":" null",
            "effective_start_date":" 2020-12-31",
            "effective_end_date":" 2021-12-31"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pattern_name":"daily_pattern_effective_start_greater_previous_effective_end",
    "cadence":"Daily",
    "cadence_start_date":"2019-05-31",
    "comments":null,
    "patterns":[
        {
            "cadence_count":1,
            "weekend_type":"Western",
            "annual_reset":"No",
            "fixed_day_of_week":null,
            "effective_start_date":"2019-05-31",
            "effective_end_date":"2021-12-31"
        },
        {
            "cadence_count":1,
            "weekend_type":" Western",
            "annual_reset":" No",
            "fixed_day_of_week":null,
            "effective_start_date":" 2022-03-31",
            "effective_end_date":" null"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pattern_name":"daily_pattern_success",
    "cadence":"Daily",
    "cadence_start_date":"2022-02-01",
    "comments":"",
    "patterns":[
        {
            "cadence_count":1,
            "weekend_type":"Western",
            "annual_reset":"No",
            "fixed_day_of_week":null,
            "effective_start_date":"2022-02-01",
            "effective_end_date":null
        }
    ]
}

]
